# Facebook join date is hidden from timeline but still visible to public

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy

I have already hidden the "Facebook join date" from my timeline (by hovering over it, selecting edit or remove (the pencil) and then *Hide it from timeline*). Right now, I cannot see this date if I go to my timeline and scroll down to the beginning. That makes sense. However, when I **view my profile as public** (by clicking the blue downward arrow just beside the Activity Log and then selecting "view as"), this "Facebook joining date" is still visible to everyone.

Is that a bug? If not, how can I hide or delete it?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete it.
However, you *can* hide it.
Go to **Activity Log**> find that post (should be on **bottom**).
If you see an icon in the right-hand side of the "post":
**Solution:**
click on it, and choose "**only me**" (you may need to click on a "**view more**" option to see it).

If you **don't** see an icon, tap on the "post" (or, on a PC, hover over it with your mouse - and, to be sure - **hover over or tap on the right-hand side**), and you should see the icon appear, then do as above, the "**Solution**".

Answer (score 0):

The activity log is only visible to yourself. So there it seems logical that you will always be able to see when you joined Facebook.

You can change the privacy of that post too, by clicking the little globe icon, and set it to only you. When you do that, and it still shows up, that would be a bug.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question correctly. To see the profile as public, I did NOT click on Activity Log. I clicked on the blue downward arrow just beside the Activity Log and then selecting "view as".

Comment: Ok, the way your question was worded before, it was confusing. But did you try the second part of my answer: click the little globe icon on that post?

Comment: I clicked on the globe icon... nothing changed. As far as I know, in facebook the globe icon is just to show that the post is public. It is not designed to change the privacy of the post.

Comment: It is though. Except that it doesn't work for me either on the joined Facebook post (and strangely enough, on 1 other post I found, the rest it works)

Answer (score 0):

When Facebook doesn't show your join date in the timeline, your friends can't view it but you can view it from an archive file.

See [How to view your Facebook join date?](http://www.obinb.com/2015/11/cach-kiem-tra-ngay-ang-ky-ngay-tham-gia.html)

Answer (score -1):

On view as public you can see (just for you), but if you enter a specific person it will not appear.